# logical operator TRUE/FALSE in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

I wrote a simple function that produces all combinations of the input (a vector). Here the input vector is basically a sequence of 4 coordinates (x, y) as mentioned inside the function as a, b,c, and d.

```
intervals<-function(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4){
  a<-c(x1,y1)
  b<-c(x2,y2)
  c<-c(x3,y3)
  d<-c(x4,y4)
  union<-expand.grid(a,b,c,d)
union
  }

intervals(2,10,3,90,6,50,82,7)


> intervals(2,10,3,90,6,50,82,7)
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1     2    3    6   82
2    10    3    6   82
3     2   90    6   82
4    10   90    6   82
5     2    3   50   82
6    10    3   50   82
7     2   90   50   82
8    10   90   50   82
9     2    3    6    7
10   10    3    6    7
11    2   90    6    7
12   10   90    6    7
13    2    3   50    7
14   10    3   50    7
15    2   90   50    7
16   10   90   50    7
>
```

Now I want to find (max of x) and (min of y) for each row of the given output. E.g. row 2: we have 4 values (10, 3, 6, 82). Here (3,6,82) are from x (x2,x3,x4) and 10 is basically from y (y1). Thus max of x is 82, and the min of y is 10.

So what I want is two values from each row.

I do not actually know how to approach this kind of logical command. Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: a matrix or data frame of dimension 16 by 2. It's better to have it like: for each row: (a, b). for example, row 2: (82, 10).

Comment: This isn't clear and I think you need to reformulate your approach - e.g. there are no `y` values in row 1 and likewise no `x` values in row 16, so how can you expect a max `x` and min `y` from each row?

Comment: rows 1 and 16 would be special cases. like empty

Comment: @RonakShah any idea? which logical function should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `x` and `y` vector separately to the function. Use `expand.grid` to create all combinations of the vector and get `max` of `x` and `min` of `y` from each row.

```
intervals<-function(x, y){
  tmp <- do.call(expand.grid, rbind.data.frame(x, y))
  names(tmp) <- paste0('col', seq_along(tmp))
  result <- t(apply(tmp, 1, function(p) {
    suppressWarnings(c(max(p[p %in% x]), min(p[p %in% y])))
  }))
  result[is.infinite(result)] <- NA
  result <- as.data.frame(result)
  names(result) <- c('max_x', 'min_x')
  result
}

intervals(c(2,3,6,82), c(10, 90, 50, 7))

#   max_x min_x
#1     82    NA
#2     82    10
#3     82    90
#4     82    10
#5     82    50
#6     82    10
#7     82    50
#8     82    10
#9      6     7
#10     6     7
#11     6     7
#12     6     7
#13     3     7
#14     3     7
#15     2     7
#16    NA     7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to use ```cat``` to get the output in the following format ```(82, NA)```?

Comment: I see that you have already asked a new question about it and got a couple of answers.

Comment: I am having a problem with this code. When there is a common element in x and y the program is not working. I am not getting any idea how to fix this one actually. I have posted the question already. In case you get time, give me a feedback